# How would I stagger text around an uneven background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Often as a Web Producer I get a lovely mock-up with text wrapping around an obvious background image. The content is going to come from a backend CMS and I don't want the editorial staff to worry about inserting `<br />` tags etc.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adiping elit,       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lao           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
hendrerit in vulputate velit esse       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
molestie consequat, vel illum         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Does anyone know of a solution to make this kind of thing automated via script, css?

Comment: I should add, that the answer I've always used, and I'm quite happy to continue using unless informed otherwise here, is "There's not an easy way to wrap around irregular images, so you either need to change your design or accept that the editors are going to be blaming you rather than me for this".

Answer (score 6):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sandbags) did an article on this a while back.  It's not totally turn-key, but they show you how to do it in PHP without too much trouble.

Comment: +1 That article does exactly what I was thinking of in my response :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely had to do this browser-side and you wanted it to be as close to 'pixel perfect' as possible (in terms of specifying things like an exact margin around the image's shape), you'll probably need to use the `<canvas>` feature of HTML 5.  With it, you would then need to do some "basic" image processing:

*this example is for an image that is to the right of the text, like your example*

1. Run an [edge-detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) algorithm on the image (probably the [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) algorithm, because of it's simplicity and speed) to find the borders.  *Alternatively*, if you can guarantee that the image will have a solid background, you could opt to simply threshold the image against that background color to obtain a [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29) of the image's subject from the background.
2. Given your `line-height`, iterate through the rows of the image to find the max distance from the image's border to the start of the image's subject (the part we segmented) for each line of text that will border the image.

   1. Take that maximum value and subtract it from the total width of the image to obtain the amount of distance from the right side of the image.
   2. Push this width onto an array `arr`.
3. At the start of the DOM node that contains your text, add `arr.length` `<div>` nodes, each of which would have

   ```
   style="height: [your text's line-height]; 
          width: [value of arr at current element]; 
          margin-left: [desired margin]; 
          float: right; clear: right"
   ```

## Edit

I wrote up a jQuery plugin for this technique, you can find it on [plugins.jquery.com](http://plugins.jquery.com) or at it's home page at http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap

Comment: While I'm some way from implementing HTML5, I've yet to look at the <code>canvas</code> element and will go and explore. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to provide a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, difficult one. Assuming your image is transparent at the left side, the closest thing I can think of is a script that finds the transparent pixels, and -- to a certain level of detail -- generates a set of floating divs that overlay the image and keep the text out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an arbitrary background image, or a fixed one? If you want to do it with any old background then you're looking at doing some serious pixel scanning, which will almost certainly have to happen at the server side and will probably not be worth your time. You're better off just baking the text into the image.

If you only want to do it for a single image your options get better, but still aren't pretty. The first thing that comes to mind is using a a monospace font, measuring how many chars can fit at each line, and then having a js function insert breaks at the appropriate string positions based on that.

Comment: Baking the text into the image would cause accessibility issues unless you chose to have a massive title attribute for the image, or did one of the tricks with text-indent or display:none to take the text off-screen.

Comment: Very true. Accessibility is always a good thing to keep in mind when designing for the web. Note that I didn't say I thought it was a GOOD idea, though :)